# How can I calculate sum with same ids to be summed and previous to be make us zero on same Resultset

Tags: java, hashmap, sum

I am getting certain values as follows:

```
no    value
2        5
2        4
2        1
4        10
4        7
1        3
5        4
```

What I am doing is follows:

```
    String outputVal  = "";
    Map<Integer, Double> sum = new HashMap<>();
                        int c1;
                        double c2;
                        while (rst.next()) {

                            c1 = rst.getInt(1);//->no
                            c2 = rst.getDouble(8);//->value
                            if (sum.containsKey(c1)) {
                                sum.put(c1, sum.get(c1) + c2);
                            } else {
                                sum.put(c1, c2);
                            }
                    outputVal = outputVal + "~" + sum.get(c1);
}


 System.out.println(outputVal );
```

So what I am getting output as:

**5~9~10~17~10~3~4**

What I need is : **0~0~10~0~17~3~4**

**It means If no remains same then sum up to total and remaining in same no should become zero.**

Comment: Just a off-topic-thought: never use `id`s multiple times `:)`

Comment: @ Tarekis `id` is an example, I used for reference. Question updated. take a look

Comment: Don't understand how you got the 0~0~10~0~17~3~4, can you clarify your algorithm.

Comment: @NAIT buddy do you understand `5~9~10~17~10~3~4`

Comment: What I need is total corresponding to a particular no should show as the final sum and the remaining should become blank(which I represented as 0). Hope you get a clear idea now.

Comment: @Santhucool I get it now, thanks.

Comment: @ NAIT  no will come as orderly so the case never happens as u mentioned